# Why can't I load images in processing.js and let them be dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html5, loading, processing

I can't easily load images. I can only render an image once unless I put this:
`<img src="images/papermario.png" hidden></img>` in my html. I also still need to be able to use..... `get(x, y, w, h)` to get the pixels of an image But I run into this error: `processing.js:13709 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.` when ever I operate it on the canvas.
   Also when I try to load the image sometimes it doesn't load.

So how should I fix it? (It still needs to be a processing js image object)

JS: 
`var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var processing = new Processing(canvas, function(processing) 
{
    processing.size(800, 800);
    processing.background(0xFFF);`

```
var mouseIsPressed = false;
processing.mousePressed = function() 
{ 
    mouseIsPressed = true; 
};
processing.mouseReleased = function() 
{ 
    mouseIsPressed = false; 
};

var keyIsPressed = false;
processing.keyPressed = function() 
{ 
    keyIsPressed = true; 
};
processing.keyReleased = function() 
{ 
    keyIsPressed = false; 
};

processing.getImage = function(url)
{
    //Loading of the home test image - img1
    var img1 = new Image();

    //drawing of the test image - img1
    img1.onload = function() 
    {
        //draw image
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

        //ctx.fillStysle = "rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5)";
        //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, img1.width, img1.height);
    };
    img1.src = url;//Set image url

    processing.externals.sketch.imageCache.add(img1.src);

    var img2 = processing.loadImage(img1.src);

    //img2.url = url;
    //img2.onload = img1.onload;

    return img2;
};

// use degrees rather than radians in rotate function
var rotateFn = processing.rotate;
processing.rotate = function(angle) 
{
    rotateFn(processing.radians(angle));
};

with (processing) 
{
    var img1 = getImage("images/papermario.png");

    //var img2 = createGraphics(180, 180, P2D);
    background(0, 0, 0);
    image(img1, 0, 0);
    //var img2 = get(0, 0, 400, 400);

    draw = function()
    {
        background(255, 255, 200);

        image(img1, 0, 0);

        //ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);s

        //image(get(0, 0, 180, 180), 80, 80);
        //var img1 = getImage("images/papermario.png");
        //img1.onload();

        //image(img2, 40, 0, 40, 40);   
        //image(img2, 0 + millis() / 1000, 0, 30, 30);
    };
}

if (typeof draw !== 'undefined') 
{
    processing.draw = draw;
}
```

});

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)?

Comment: Yes, but It doesn't solve the problem... I need specific code for processing js because it has a special image object

Comment: In that case I'm not really sure if I understand what the issue is.

Comment: I actually got it working in Cordova, I just need a way to set the ACAO header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load and use images from other domains with HTML5 canvas. Make sure to serve your images from the same domain/server as your processing code. Alternatively, enable cross origin access on the server which is serving your image.

Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data

Comment: I've now ran it from a server... Now how do I set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header?

Comment: Cordova that is.

Comment: Haven’t worked with Cordova before but did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398695/cors-cordova-issues-with-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: You could also try storing the image inside the HTML document itself using base64. I haven’t tried this but it might work http://base64image.org/